# Proof for a Legendre polynomial identity on a 2-sphere that appears in cosmology

Tags: legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

How can I prove the following identity?

\begin{equation}
\int d\Omega_{\hat k} P_l(\hat n \cdot \hat k) P_{l'}(\hat n'\cdot \hat k)=\frac{4\pi}{2l+1} P_l(\hat n\cdot \hat n')\delta_{ll'}\label{PP}
\end{equation}

Both hand-waving one and rigorous one are welcome

Comment: Can you precise what $\hat n, \hat n^\prime, \hat k$ are ?

Comment: $\hat n$ and $\hat n'$ are arbitrary normalized 3-d vector pointing two points in 2-sphere. $\hat k$ is a normalized 3-d vector pointing a point in 2-sphere. The integration is over 2-sphere measure $d\Omega$.

Comment: When $\hat n=\hat n'$ you get the ordinary orthogonal property of Legendre polynomial as $\hat n\cdot\hat n'=1$.

Comment: Has this anything to do with the Wikipedia article [Spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)?

Comment: I don't think so.